# jQuery - contains / filter and insertBefore to rearrange a list (div > ul > li) issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

After a paid integration between our E-Commerce system and POS system, my online store is now showing sizes in Alphabetical/Chronological order. 
Eg.
`L | M | S | XL` instead of `S | M | L | XL`
And

```
7 | 7 1/2 | 7 1/4 | 7 1/8 | 7 3/8
```

This is because the size attributes/options are now being pulled from the POS system and is unique for each product (silly, I know but that's how the integration works). This means that it's not possible to manually select the order for them to appear as this will require thousands of manual changes which defeats the purpose of the integration.

I have come up with a jQuery solution but have ran into a few problems.
I have applied this to Numerical and Alphabetical sizing and have the same problem.

```
$(".Value li:contains('XL')").insertBefore($(".Value li:contains('XXL')"));
$(".Value li:contains('L')").insertBefore($(".Value li:contains('XL')"));
$(".Value li:contains('M')").insertBefore($(".Value li:contains('L')"));
$(".Value li:contains('S')").insertBefore($(".Value li:contains('M')"));
$(".Value li:contains('XS')").insertBefore($(".Value li:contains('S')"));
```

This works fine until you get to a single character value which has a sister value. In other words that code will rearrange L M S into S M L just fine, but it runs into problems if there is a XS or XL, or in the case of numerical sizes getting down to a single digit. Such as a size 7 if there are 7 1/4, 7 1/8 etc. 
This is obviously because of the .contains() function.

I have tried using .filter() but I can't get it to select the elements I want let alone .insertBefore

Thanks.

---

Edit with HTML as requested:

```
<div class="Value">
    <ul>
            <li>
    <label><input name="variation[1]" type="radio" class="RadioButton" value="5429"  /> XL</label>
</li>   <li>
    <label><input name="variation[1]" type="radio" class="RadioButton" value="5430"  /> 2XL</label>
</li>   <li>
    <label><input name="variation[1]" type="radio" class="RadioButton" value="5431"  /> M</label>
</li>   <li>
    <label><input name="variation[1]" type="radio" class="RadioButton" value="5432"  /> L</label>
</li>   <li>
    <label><input name="variation[1]" type="radio" class="RadioButton" value="5433"  /> S</label>
</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

Edit 2

As can be seen from the above HTML and what I've just realised - it's not displaying in Alphabetical / Chronological order of the labels (size), but rather chronologically for the radio buttons value. As mentioned this is generated dynamically by the shopping cart when importing products from our POS.

Comment: Please show us your actual HTML for the sizes.  Is each size string in it's own LI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how general purpose a function you need, but this code will sort the HTML you posted and can be passed other selectors and other key orders:

```
function sortLabels(ulSelector, order) {
    var parent = $(ulSelector);
    var items = $("li", parent).each(function() {
        // get text out of the label and trim
        var txt = $.trim($(this).find("label").text());
        // get order number
        var num = order[txt] || 0;
        // save this on the DOM object for easier sorting
        this.sortKey = num;
    }).get().sort(function(a, b) {
        // sort DOM array
        return(a.sortKey - b.sortKey);
    });

    // reinsert DOM elements in order
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        parent.append(items[i]);
    }
}

var sizeOrdinals = {
    "XS": 1, "S": 2, "M": 3, "L": 4, 
    "XL": 5, "XXL": 6, "2XL": 7
};
sortLabels(".Value ul", sizeOrdinals);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/B45tJ/

By simply defining a new table of ordinals, you can use this to sort other types of values like shoe sizes without rewriting the sortLabels function.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I needed as it took into consideration the gaps that occur when not all sizes are present.

Answer (score 2):

Add this jQuery function in your file:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.whichContains = function(content) {
        return this.filter(function() {
                return $(this).text().trim() == content;
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

and in your jquery script try with this formula:

```
$(".Value li").whichContains('XL').insertBefore($(".Value li").whichContains('2XL'));
```

For more Info, see this JSFiddle Link:

http://jsfiddle.net/UcbU2/1/

Comment: Excellent response Chinmay, it answered my question exactly. It worked and I was going to use it however it left a problem which was if there was a gap in sizing.

i.e. if the sizing went 30 31 33 34 35 and was jumbled. It would not put 31 before 33 because it only puts it before 32. Thus I used jfriends solution above.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom sorter to sort the list items by sizes on an Array List. This way, if you need to add new sizes to your page, just update the array on the sort function!

```
var sortSizes = [],
allLi = $("div.Value li"),
newLi = "";

// Pushing list items onto the sort Array with its size
allLi.each(function() {
    sortSizes.push(new Array($.trim($(this).text()), $('<div>').append($(this).clone()).remove().html()));
});
// Sort by index of its size in the size array below
sortSizes = sortSizes.sort(sizes);
// Get the new list of sorted LIs
for (i = 0, l = sortSizes.length; i < l; i++) {
    newLi += sortSizes[i][1];
}
// Add this sorted LI to the UL
$("div.Value ul").html(newLi);
// Size sorter
function sizes(a, b) {
    var size = ["S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL"],
        a = $.inArray(a[0], size),
        b = $.inArray(b[0], size);
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
}​
```

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kayen/rgQr3/2/

Comment: Comments, suggestions, improvements from the jQuery gurus to this approach welcome!

Comment: In your `sizes()` function, you can just do `return(a-b)`.  Why do you need to `.clone()` anything?  Why do you need to create new HTML.  You are recreating these elements twice, when you can just move the existing DOM elements.  Using an object to look up a sort value for the size is much faster than a linear array search.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but found this question interesting
Here is how I would do it:

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6QpjM/)*

```
var size = ['XS','S','M','L','XL','XXL', '2XL'];
function sorty(a,b){
    var AA = $(a).data('size'),
        BB = $(b).data('size');
    return (AA<BB) ? -1 : (AA>BB) ? 1 : 0;
}
$('div.Value ul').each(function(ix, UL){  
    $('li', UL).each(function(ix, LI){
      for(i=0;i<size.length;i++){
        if( $.trim($(LI).find('label').text().toUpperCase()) === size[i]){
            $(LI).data('size', i);
        }
      }
    });
    $(UL).append( $('li',UL).sort(sorty) );
});
```

- Create an array of sizes (from smaller)
- Create a sort custom function `sorty()` that will sort elements `.data()`
- Iterate trough the texts of each `LI --> LABEL` elements for each `UL` inside a `for` loop.
- If the text (`trim()` whitespaces and `toUpperCase()` to fix mistakes) matches an array - set the parent `li` a `data-size-N`, where N is the returned array index number (`size[i]`).
- Now that each `LI` has a data like: `data-size="N"` we can use our function `sorty` to append to `UL` the sorted LI's.